# Debugging errors that were not caught by Application_Error()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, runtime-error, web-deployment

I have an MVC3 (C#) application that threw up a mysterious error (displaying a custom error page) that I didn't have found any information about it in both my log file (I use NLog for logging) and IIS log.

The fact that it does not turn up in my log file, I conclude that Application_Error() didn't fire because otherwise it should have been logged. Once this error occurred, it won't go away until I restart application pool.

**Note:** this is not about Application_Error() doesn't fire when customError is On. Even though I have customError set as On. Because when I deliberately put a wrong URL, I get custom error page and I can see it in the log as well.

Anyone has experienced similar issue? Or anyone has any idea what I should look into? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like an IIS error.  Those don't get caught by the application, because they never make it to the application in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch any URL on a given domain, you need what's called a catch-all route, like this:

```
// this route is intended to catch 404 Not Found errors instead of bubbling them all the way up to IIS.
routes.MapRoute("PageNotFound", "{*catchall}", notFound);
```

Register that route last.

On the "take over IIS hijacking" aspect of the question, you might want to research [system.webServer httpErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Nico, thank you for your reply. I would consider the catch-all route for some improvement in my application. At the moment I will look into system.webServer.httpErrors. 

Did you suggest that the error might be on the IIS level rather than on Application level?

Comment: uncaught routes can't be handled by your application, since it won't be handling those requests, and therefore a 404 will be thrown.

Comment: What is `notFound` supposed to be?

Comment: `private static readonly object notFound = new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" };`